# My costume widget is not showing in a Column

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, widget

So i have created a costume widget and i wanted to show it in a column, but whenever i put it in a column and run the application the widget doesn't show on the screen.

This is my costume Widget

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FractionallySizedBox(
              widthFactor: 1,
              heightFactor: 0.3,
              child: Container(
                child: new LineChart(linechartData()),
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
              ),
            );
  }
```

and this is my main.dart widget

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: new Text("hello"),
        ),
        body: new Container(
            child: new Column(
          children: [
            new Container(child: new Text("hello")),          
            new Chart()],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Ive tried to check if the problem is with the column widget by removing my costume widget from the column widget and by putting a text widget but the text widget shows fine the problem is when i add my costume widget inside it that everything desapears

Comment: fyi, I think you meant to say "custom". Not "costume". A costume is a set of clothes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your widget inside the `Flexible` one, like this:

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: new Text("hello"),
        ),
        body: new Container(
            child: new Column(
          children: [
            new Flexible(child: Costume()),
            new Chart()],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

CHeckout [FractionallySizedBox (Flutter Widget of the Week)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEsY654EGZ0) video

Comment: thank you man it works now, can you explain why it needs Flexible?

Comment: @gemchugeme column and row children don't have height and width bounds, so the `FractionallySizedBox` is not able to calculate it's size because it's available height and width are equal to zero. When using Flexible or Expanded you basically say to Column "hey, this children should fill all available width and height:

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `FractionallySizedBox` with `Expanded` to get available height and then `heightFactor` will be used its child

```dart
body: Container(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        child: new Text("hello"),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
          widthFactor: 1,
          heightFactor: 0.3,
          child: Container(
            
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Also you might be interested on [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)